# How to calculate eigenvalues using QR method?

Tags: java, apache, math, linear-algebra, apache-commons-math

How can I get eigenvalues of matrix using Apache Commons Math? I know there is 2 classes EigenDecomposition and QRDecomposition, but how to combine them to get eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0):

Why combine them?  QR can give you eigenvalues:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm

Comment: Yep, but how I can get eigenvalues using [QRDecomposition](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/QRDecomposition.html)?

Comment: are you really this lazy?  http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/QRMethodMod.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse the QR decomposition with the QR eigenvalue algorithm.

The QR decomposition cannot give you the eigenvalues of a matrix, but it can be used as a component to a more complex algorithm that produce eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition